# Neovim colorscheme flickers momentarily in tmux when opening C/C++ files

Tags: command-line-interface, tmux, neovim, alacritty

The weird thing only happens when I open a C/C++ file. What I doing wrong here?

#### The moment when .cpp file open up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z78O.png)

#### About 0.1 sec later.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPZQS.png)

#### The version of related app and os.

```
nvim v0.10.0-dev
tmux 3.2a
alacritty 0.13.0-dev
Ubuntu 22.04
```

#### The theme and plugin what I used:

```
use 'morhetz/gruvbox'
use 'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter'
```

#### This is what I have in my legacy.vim

```
" Colorscheme
set termguicolors
let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark='dark'  
let g:gruvbox_contrast_light='hard' 
colorscheme gruvbox   
hi LspCxxHlGroupMemberVariable guifg=#83a598
```

#### This is my $TERM

insdie tmux:

```
$ echo $TERM
screen-256color
```

and in alacritty:

```
$ echo $TERM
alacritty
```

#### What i've tried so far:

in my .tmux.conf I tried

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -ag terminal-overrides ",screen-256color:RGB"
set -sa terminal-overrides ",screen-256color:RGB"
```

and

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set-option -sa terminal-features ',screen-256color:RGB'
```

These doesn't work.

If I tried this in .tmux.conf file. Some of the colors would change, but there would still be a momentary flickering.

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set-option -sa terminal-features ',alacritty:RGB'
```

and

```
$ tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

#### The moment when .cpp file open up.

[image]

#### About 0.1 sec later.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the solution.

The reason is that there is a legacy parser from before. I didn't not clean the settings properly.

Before reinstalling Neovim, I used the :checkhealth command to check out the status.

The Nvim runtime ABI version is 14, but Parser C is 13.

```
vim.treesitter: require("vim.treesitter.health").check()
========================================================================
- Nvim runtime ABI version: 14
- OK Parser: bash       ABI: 14, path: /home/david/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-treesitter/parser/bash.so
- OK Parser: c          ABI: 13, path: /home/david/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-treesitter/parser/c.so
- OK Parser: cpp        ABI: 14, path: /home/david/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-treesitter/parser/cpp.so
- OK Parser: python     ABI: 14, path: /home/david/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-treesitter/parser/python.so
- OK Parser: c          ABI: 13, path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvim/parser/c.so
- OK Parser: lua        ABI: 13, path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvim/parser/lua.so
- OK Parser: query      ABI: 14, path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvim/parser/query.so
- OK Parser: vim        ABI: 14, path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvim/parser/vim.so
- OK Parser: vimdoc     ABI: 14, path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvim/parser/vimdoc.so
```

So, I reinstall neovim, and clean all the settings in  ~/.local/share/nvim.
and checkout status again. And it works!

```
vim.treesitter: require("vim.treesitter.health").check()
========================================================================
  - INFO: Runtime ABI version : 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for bash: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for c: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for cpp: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for lua: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for python: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for query: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for vim: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for vimdoc: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for c: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for help: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for lua: ABI version 14
  - OK: Loaded parser for vim: ABI version 14
```